# Error: Cannot find module ' buffer-shims'

Tags: javascript, node.js, homebrew

I am working on a Reactjs project and was in the process of installing Electron. Every time I tried to install Electron globally I didn't have permission. I thought that by installing Homebrew I wouldn't run into this problem anymore. However, it created a bigger issue. I uninstalled homebrew to go back to my base. Now, every time I run NPM I get this error message:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'buffer-shims'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
at Object.<anonymous> 
(/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/readable-
stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:36:18)
at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

Comment: Have you tried installing the missing module?

Comment: did u try ``npm install``? and review your ``package.json``?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on my Mac. When I was trying to update `npm`.

`/usr/local/lib/node_modules` was owned by root and not by me on my machine.

I did a `sudo chown -R <username_here> /usr/local/lib/node_modules` on that directory. Then I deleted the whole directory `rm -r /usr/local/lib/node_modules` and then did a `brew uninstall npm` and a `brew reinstall npm` to fix this issue.